# Insert order data from csv programatically in Magento 2.2

Tags: mysql, php-7, magento2.2

I have 2 different CSV files 1st has orders and 2nd have order details. I am trying to insert data into magento2 DB using Magento Models. so that my data will insert into all different tables and will also show on the Admin side.

Right now I have inserted data in DB but the data is just inserted into **sales_order** table, all the other tables related to orders are empty, that's why order's data is not showing on the Admin side.

**Need some serious help**

Comment: You have not followed the proper Magento Modeling... Show us your code so we can help you.

Comment: I don't know how to do.